# Deriving Show in a generic struct

Tags: rust, traits, bounds

I am trying to understand a some concepts in Rust but I am stuck in a very simple problem. I am trying to define a struct which I then want to print. If I specify the type of the components (in the example replace `T` by `f32`), everything is fine. But if I want to do it generically:

```
#[deriving(Show)]
struct Point<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
    z: T,
}

fn main() {
    let v = Point{x: 3., y: 4., z: 5.,};
    println!("The point is {}" , v);
}
```

The output in http://play.rust-lang.org/ is:

> error: unable to infer enough type information to locate the impl of
>   the trait `core::fmt::Show` for the type `_`; type annotations
>   required

If I try to specify the type:

```
use std::fmt;

#[deriving(Show)]
struct Point<T: std::fmt::Show> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
    z: T,
}

fn main() {
    let v = Point{x: 3., y: 4., z: 5.,};
    println!("The point is {}" , v);
}
```

The output is:

> error: trait `std::fmt::Show` already appears in the list of bounds
>   [E0127] previous appearance is here #[deriving(Show)]

Why is this? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3.` isn't specific enough to name a type on it's own - it could be either `f32` of `f64`. You could be more explicit in (at least) these two ways:

```
let v = Point{x: 3f32, y: 4f32, z: 5f32};
let v: Point<f32> = Point{x: 3., y: 4., z: 5.};
```

Comment: I thought I was underspecifying the struct, not that I was instantiating the struct wrong.

Comment: @Hernan: The first error is indeed caused by underspecifying the struct's members. The second error seems to be caused by `#[deriving(Show)]` automatically adding the `Show` bound on `T`; by also adding it yourself, it ends up appearing twice.